# Not receiving some messages with status_type "shared_story" using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph, shared, facebook-stream-story

I've been searching about this many hours since I saw I'm not receiving some of my friends posts in my app. I looked at the [FQL documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/), searched through the Internet, but nothing.

I now that I can get them with the Graph API, asking for "feed" but I receive a lot of types of posts I don't need because of that I began to use FQL asking for ["stream"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) where I can specify a few types (46 - Status update, 80 - Link posted, etc).

This type of posts are made in a wall of a person when he/she shares the status, photo or link another person posted in his wall, this is the "status_type": "shared_story".

Someone knows if it is possible to get them with FQL?

Thank you.

P.S.: Ok, this is crazy, I saw one post of this type that I get with FQL and I asked for feed using the Graph API and the type is the same "shared_story". But for some reason I don't understand I don't get all of them. Is there another parameter that could make the difference between them? Because I don't see it.

I'm not receiving this:

```
{
     "id": "",
     "from": {
        "name": "",
        "id": ""
     },
     "story": "",
     "story_tags": {
        "0": [
           {
              "id": "",
              "name": "",
              "offset": 0,
              "length": 24,
              "type": "user"
           }
        ],
        "32": [
           {
              "id": "",
              "name": "",
              "offset": 32,
              "length": 18,
              "type": "page"
           }
        ]
     },
     "picture": "",
     "link": "",
     "name": "s",
     "caption": "",
     "properties": [
        {
           "name": "",
           "text": "",
           "href": ""
        }
     ],
     "icon": "",
     "actions": [
        {
           "name": "Comment",
           "link": ""
        },
        {
           "name": "Like",
           "link": "4"
        }
     ],
     "privacy": {
        "value": ""
     },
     "type": "photo",
     "status_type": "shared_story",
     "object_id": "",
     "application": {
        "name": "Links",
        "id": "2309869772"
     },
     "created_time": "",
     "updated_time": "",
     "likes": {
        "data": [
           {
              "name": "",
              "id": ""
           }
        ],
        "count": 1
     },
     "comments": {
        "count": 0
     }
  }
```

But, I'm receiving this:

```
{
     "id": "",
     "from": {
        "name": "",
        "id": ""
     },
     "message": "",
     "picture": "",
     "link": "",
     "source": "",
     "name": "",
     "caption": "",
     "description": "",
     "icon": "",
     "actions": [
        {
           "name": "Comment",
           "link": ""
        },
        {
           "name": "Like",
           "link": ""
        }
     ],
     "privacy": {
        "value": ""
     },
     "type": "video",
     "status_type": "shared_story",
     "application": {
        "name": "Links",
        "id": "2309869772"
     },
     "created_time": "",
     "updated_time": "",
     "comments": {
        "count": 0
     }
  }
```